# Guide for Facebook App

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

I'm developing a facebook app and also checked every possible areas including
'secure canvas url', 'app domain', 'oauth' section. But it's not loading inside canvas.
Code works normal in facebook js-sdk console, but the canvas frame is totally empty showing 'operation timed out'. What is the problem? 
Please guide me.

Comment: post your code so that we can look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first call to a Canvas app (by Facebook) is always a POST request IMHO. Please check if your application supports POST requests as well, instead of only GETs.

To make sure, please have a look at your browser's developer console / network tab and have a look what request are actually executed.